# how to remove list tile separator flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to remove the line under the list tile item like in the image : [image]

..
note that my list tile is  without ListView  here is my code :

```
   ListTile(

 leading: ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),child:Image.memory(base64Decode(society['image'])
   title: Text(society['Society_Name']   ),),
  trailing: ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
  }, child: Icon(Icons.email_outlined, size: 25,), style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: green),),
  ),
```

Comment: Image not Display, Please add proper image

Comment: https://ibb.co/59X3y5n

Comment: sry , i have edited the question

Comment: ListTile doesn't have any line. Do you wrap it with a card or anything else?

Comment: Oops, thanks alot @Anneress i noticed that i wrapped it with Container with border

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and use [Themes](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes)

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
  child: ListTile(
    title: Text(
      'Hello, World!',
    ),
  ),
),
```